# Spring MVC Object Creation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have used spring mvc in a few projects. In my experience, when building a form, for example, the spring equivalent of the various html form elements is used, for example a spring form instead of the normal form tag. My understanding was that was necessary so that if the backend controller was building a business object for you from the request attributes , the mapping between the form elements and the object attributes could be made. However, I have come across a normal html form that did not have the spring elements, and the backend controller still constructed the object. What is the advantage of using spring form elements as opposed to regular form elements?

Comment: Data is submitted over HTTP. While creating model objects, Controller does  not care how was the html created. Are you asking why do we use tag libraries ?

Answer (score 2):

JSP tags, in general, are only used to generate HTML. So, generating "by hand" the same HTML as the one generated by the JSP tags of course leads to the same result: Spring has no way to know if a HTTP request it receives has been generated by a form using its own tags or something else.

The advantage is conciseness, and less repetition:

```
<form:input path="name" />
```

is more concise, and has less risks of introducing a bug, than

```
<input name="name" type="text" value="<c:out value='${command.name}'/>" />
```

Some tags are more advanced, and generate, for example, a whole list of `<option>` elements based on a collection you give to the tag.

As always, learn by reading [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-jsp-formtaglib).

Comment: Right, but I guess my confusion is that in the servlet you usually manually retrieve the parameters from the request, and then build a business object from them. Spring can do that work for you simply by specifying in the controller method the business object as another parameter. In the case of a spring form tag, i wasn't sure what benefits it afforded you vs a normal html form

Comment: Populating the object from the request simply works based on the request parameters: If your bean has a property foo and a property bar, Spring will populate them with the request parameters named foo and bar. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Ive seen some maps as parameters in spring controller methods, not quite sure how that works. For simple business objects i see how the connection is made, but not so much with things like maps.

Comment: AFAIR, parameters foo[bar] and foo[baz] woll populate the keys "bar" and "baz" of the map "foo".